# Get coefficients of complex equation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get coefficients of the following equation:

[image]

My code is:

```
args=[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,-5,0];
a=args(1);b=args(2);c=args(3);d=args(4);e=args(5);f=args(6);g=args(7);h=args(8);m=args(9);s=args(10); %M=i  , j = s

syms x y z real


Q=[a,d,e,g;
   d,b,f,h;
   e,f,c,m;
   g,h,m,s];
X=[x,y,z,1]';

func(x,y,z)=X'*Q*X;

[A,B]=coeffs(func)
```

My problem is that I don't get coefficients all those with zeros values
my result should be :
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,-5,0]

I get :
[ 1, 1, 1, -10]

How do I get the zeros as well

Comment: What do you need the coefficients for? Do you want to estimate them from some data?

Comment: this is small part from complex program. to make long story short I try to convert equation from one coordinate system to another. I want to convert the parameters of the equation. my input is equation parameters, the translation and rotation matrix

Comment: In that case, you can just multiply your matrix `Q` with the transformation matrix `T`: `Qtransformed = T*Q*T'`, no?

Comment: Let say that transformation matrix are T_m_i=[3,3,3];
R_m_i=eye(3,3); sohow do I multiply  does with Q?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I found is:

```
[parameters,Eqations]=coeffs(funcToConvert)
parameters= sym2poly(parameters(x,y,z));

EqationsCells=arrayfun(@char,Eqations(x,y,z),'Un',0);


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[x^2, 1, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    a=0;
else
    a=parameters(index);
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[x, x, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    d=0;
else
    d=parameters(index)/2;
end

SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[x, 1, x]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    e=0;
else
    e=parameters(index)/2;
end



SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[x, 1, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    g=0;
else
    g=parameters(index)/2;
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, x^2, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    b=0;
else
    b=parameters(index);
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, x, x]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    f=0;
else
    f=parameters(index)/2;
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, x, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    h=0;
else
    h=parameters(index)/2;
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, 1, x^2]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    c=0;
else
    c=parameters(index);
end


SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, 1, x]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    m=0;
else
    m=parameters(index)/2;
end



SerachRes=Myeq(EqationsCells,{'matrix([[1, 1, 1]])'});
index= GetSearchIndex( SerachRes );
if 0==index
    s=0;
else
    s=parameters(index);
end
```

But it seem no so efficient